# How to send multipart response?

Tags: c#, web-services, nancy

I have a service whereby I need to send a multipart response with different content types. I couldn't find any examples on how to do that with Nancy.

Is it supported in Nancy? If so, can you point me to an example?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32465725/625521) can help (not sure about multiple parts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in to do this so you'll have to construct your own Response type and/or corresponding Processor to build the multipart response.